# Wrong username and password

Tags: php, authentication

I created the code below for people to login on a site but the results keep saying:

> wrong username or password

and I don't know what's wrong. The database has a table "clients" with columns names "usernames" and "passwords".

```
<?php
$host = ""; // Host name
$username = ""; // Mysql username
$password = ""; // Mysql password
$db_name = ""; // Database name
$tbl_name = "clients"; // Table name
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");
$username = $_POST['myusername'];
$password = $_POST['mypassword'];
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql = "SELECT `username` FROM `clients` WHERE `username`='$myusername' and         `password`='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row

if ($result) {
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
}
else {
    $count = 0;
}

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if ($count == 1) {

    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword");
    header("location:source/login_success.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

?>
```

Comment: You're initialising `$username`, and then using `$myusername`, and the same for password. You're always going to be passing two empty fields into your query, and hence getting no results.

Comment: [Turn on your error reporting in apache](http://www.hiddenwebgenius.com/blog/web-development/basic-php-error-reporting-techniques/)

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` extensions for new code. You can google why.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is here:

```
$username = $_POST['myusername'];
$password = $_POST['mypassword'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername); // Using uninitialized '$myusername'
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword); // Using uninitialized '$mypassword'
```

`$myusername` and `$mypassword` are unitialized when passed to `stripslashes()`, so the result will always be empty.

To correct this problem, adjust the variable names passed to `stripslashes()`:

```
$myusername = stripslashes($username);
$mypassword = stripslashes($password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
```

to this:

```
$myusername = stripslashes($username);
$mypassword = stripslashes($password);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea not to register the password in the session. A better practice is to set the session with the id of the user (say that in your mysql table, you have: id, username, password, etc.). It is a better and more secure way to do. And then, on the pages that you require to be logged in, you just do:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) {
..... display error message and redirect user to login page....
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

$username = $_POST['myusername'];

$password = $_POST['mypassword'];

TRY THIS

$myusername = $_POST['myusername'];

$mypassword = $_POST['mypassword'];